# TinyMCE copy and paste source code from clipboard

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to customize TinyMCE with additional functionalities.
I'd like to add two additional items to menu - paste HTML and copy HTML.

Inside `setup` I'm adding two menu items:

```
editor.addMenuItem('htmlPaste', {
  text: 'Paste HTML',
  icon: 'paste',
  context: 'file',
  onclick: function() {
    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span> html');
    editor.notificationManager.open({
      text: 'HTML pasted.',
      type: 'info',
      timeout: 2000,
      closeButton: false
    });
  }
});
editor.addMenuItem('htmlCopy', {
  text: 'Copy HTML',
  icon: 'copy',
  context: 'file',
  onclick: function() {
    editor.notificationManager.open({
      text: 'HTML copied.',
      type: 'info',
      timeout: 2000,
      closeButton: false
    });
  }
});
```

Part missing is clipboard access. I was thinking about using clipboard.js, but I realized that TinyMCE has this build in, but it copies and paste normal content not HTML source.

Can I use build in functionality of TinyMCE to access clipboard? So when I click `Paste HTML` TinyMCE will update underlying source code of content and when I click `Copy HTML` TinyMCE will copy source code to clipboard (here I'd like to add some modifications (replace tags) before setting clipboard content).

I'd like to use this feature, because TinyMCE supports fallback when user has disabled clipboard access.

Here is my prototype on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWbpyr

**EDIT:**
Looking thru GitHub I found some useful functions like [setClipboardData](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/136c0341aa9f43b720d5942498ed1796f1cb2ccf/src/plugins/paste/src/main/js/core/CutCopy.js#L35) but still I don't know how to call it from my code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to do what you want on most modern browsers.

If you try to use the built in Cut/Copy/Paste buttons in TinyMCE you see this for most browsers:

> "Your browser doesn't support direct access to the clipboard. Please
>   use the Ctrl+X/C/V keyboard shortcuts instead."

As the message from the editor states this is simply a limitation of what you can / cannot do directly via JavaScript in certain browsers.

Imagine what you could do if your arbitrary JavaScript could access the clipboard whenever it liked? "Bad people" don't play by the rules so what if (upon loading a web page) they had JavaScript that grabbed everything from the clipboard and sent it to their servers? Over time the browser manufacturers realized that direct access to the clipboard was "bad" ... by having the user type CRTL+C and CRTL+V you are effectively telling the browser you want it to access the clipboard.

IE11 does indeed allow access via legacy APIs but Edge at present does not support the clipboard APIs at all (at least not at the time I write this).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm aware that I wan't be able to get clipboard content, but probably I will be able to set clipboard content. I can show `Tools->Source code` and allow user to paste source code that he has in his clipboard. But there is the second part, I'd like to be able to copy html content using button, menu item or keyboard shortcut. I know that user can go to `Tools->Source code` and copy it there, but I want to replace some tags so I can't use that panel. I just check in latest Chrome, and as You wrote paste does not work, but copy option does.